# How to inline styles with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Is there a way for webpack to inline styles automatically?

For example, with some sample CSS,

```
.example { 
    font-size: 2em 
}
```

And some HTML inside a Component,

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className={css.example} />
    }
}
```

I'd want webpack to output:
`<div style="font-size: 2em;" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that does this:

https://github.com/Automattic/juice

It works perfectly, though it doesn't use webpack which I prefer.

Answer (score -3):

In your  component render function before you return:

```
const style = {
     // your styles here as an object  convert hyphenated css property names to camelCase and pass a string as the value
     backgroundColor: 'blue' 
}
```

Then in the element:

```
<p style={style} >  content </p>
```

Comment: That's not what I need.  I already have styles loaded with style-loader.  I need to inline styles for emails, and I'd rather keep the same components I use for web.